# Angular 4 & PrimeNg: how to add and remove/hide tab-panels

Tags: html, angular, typescript, primeng

I have a tabView and a list of tab-panels. 
Based on runtime conditions, I need to hide and unhide one of the tab panels.
Can not find a way to do this using looking at their docs or here.
Any suggestions?

In general is there a way to dynamically add and remove tab panels?

Code I am using now that is not working, my test syntax must be wrong:

```
                <div [ngSwitch]="isNEC">
                <ng-template ngSwitchCase="'true'">
                <p-tabView>
                    <p-tabPanel header="Detail">
                        <linechart #linechart></linechart>
                    </p-tabPanel>
                    <p-tabPanel header="Assessment">
                        Coming soon to a theater near you !!!!
                    </p-tabPanel>
                </p-tabView>
                </ng-template>
                <ng-template ngSwitchCase="'false'">
                    <p-tabView>
                        <p-tabPanel header="Detail">
                            <linechart #linechart></linechart>
                        </p-tabPanel>
                    </p-tabView>
                </ng-template>

            </div>
```

unless I put a switch default, nothing ever shows up.
isNEC is a component public attribute of type string

Comment: Can you share some of your code?

Comment: Have you tried adding an `*ngIf` to the panel that you need to show or hide? I don't see any reason why that wouldn't work.

Comment: I am using ngSwitch right now.

Comment: edited the original post

Answer (score 0):

all is well, I just needed to check for 'true' and not "'true'"